# Положение картинки

Tags: php, html

Я начал изучать php не давно.
  Мне нужно сделать что бы картинка была не всамом углу 
А отступало с верху примерно 5 см. и с низу 5 см.
Стандартные не помогают(<p></p>,center)
Помогите
А ещё подскажите книжку какую нибудь хорошую по php.Спасибо

Comment: К php ни какого отношения не имеет. Это html и css.

Comment: что мне делать?

Не я тож смотрел css и присваивал стиль что бы менять положение но не получилось

Comment: Отступает только от верха, а от сторон нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что за картинка где она?
Прочитай про свойства [margin](http://htmlbook.ru/css/margin) и [padding](http://htmlbook.ru/css/padding).
В данном случае нужно padding, видимо. 
в css пиши

```
.avatar {               /* название класса */
         padding: 50px; /*например по 50 пикселей со всех четырех сторон*/
    }
```

Comment: Ну вернее не "img" иначе всем картинкам свойство присвоится. Лучше по id сделать или класс, если картинок таких много.

Comment: Код:

    <img alt='аватар'  src='$myrow[avatar]'/><br>

Comment: Отлично сказано!

Comment: Если такая картинка единственная на странице, то присвоить ей id - <img id='avatar' alt='аватар' src='$myrow[avatar]'/>. В css не "img" написать, а "#avatar". Должно сработать.

Comment: У меня на странице эта фотография повторяеться 2 раза (ничего не измениться)

Comment: Тогда лучше класс 

    <img class='avatar' alt='аватар' src='$myrow[avatar]'/>

В css - `.avatar{padding: 50px;}`

Comment: Так?

    .avatar {
        padding: 50px; /*например*/
     }

Answer (score 0):

.avatar {             
         margin: 50px; 
    }

<img    class='avatar' alt='аватар' src='$myrow[avatar]'/> должен работать.

Comment: СПАСИБО всё работает